# My basic trade program in C does not store any modifications when I close command prompt

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {  
   //After selling and buying i want it to modify this 
   struct music {
       int srno;
       char name[10];
       int upperlimit;
       int lowerlimit;
       int avarn;
 };

//Structure to maintain personal data
struct custormer {
    int srno;
    char name[5];
    int upperlimit;
    int lowerlimit;
    int avarn;
};

FILE *f1;
int choice,amount,price;
int x,code,j=0;


struct music m1[] = {1,"Apple",100,98,10,2,"Valve",100,98,10,3,"Google",90,80,10,4,"Tesla",100,98,10};
struct music m2[10];

f1 = fopen("4.DAT","rb+");
if(f1==NULL)
{
    printf("File does not exist!");
    exit(0);
}

while(1)
{
    printf("___________________________________\n");
    printf("MENU\n");
    printf("___________________________________\n");
    printf("1) Stock Market\n");
    printf("2) Buy\n");
    printf("3) Personal Info\n");
    printf("4) Sell\n");
    printf("5) Exit\n");

    printf("Enter choice:");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            printf("Stock Market\n");
            printf("___________________________________\n");
            for(x=0;x<4;x++)
            {
                printf("%d\t %s\t %d\t %d\t %d\n",m1[x].srno,m1[x].name,m1[x].upperlimit,m1[x].lowerlimit,m1[x].avarn);
                fwrite(&m1,sizeof(m1),1,f1);
            }
            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            printf("Enter code of Stock:");
            scanf("%d",&code);

            printf("Enter number of stocks:");
            scanf("%d",&amount);

            printf("Enter price:");
            scanf("%d",&price);

            rewind(f1);
            for(x=0;x<4;x++)
            {
                if(price>m1[x].lowerlimit&&price<m1[x].upperlimit)
                {

                    if(m1[x].srno==code)
                        {
                            printf("Trasaction Is Succesful\n");
                            m1[x].avarn = m1[x].avarn-amount;
                            fwrite(&m1,sizeof(m1),1,f1);

                            m2[j].srno = j+1;
                            strcpy(m2[j].name,m1[x].name);
                            m2[j].avarn = amount;
                            j++;
                        }
                }

            }
        break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
            for(x=0;x<j;x++)
            {
                printf("%d\t %s\t %d\n ",m2[x].srno,m2[x].name,m2[x].avarn);
                fseek ( f1, sizeof(m1), SEEK_CUR ) ;
                fwrite ( &m2, sizeof(m2), 1, f1 ) ;
            }

            break;
        }

    case 4:
        {
            printf("Enter code of stock to sell:");
            scanf("%d", &code);

            printf("Enter amount to sell:");
            scanf("%d",&amount);

            printf("Enter price to sell:");
            scanf("%d",&price);

            for(x=0;x<4;x++)
            {
                if(price>m1[x].lowerlimit&&price<m1[x].upperlimit)
                {
                    if(m1[x].srno==code)
                    {
                        printf("Transaction is Sucessful\n");
                        m1[x].avarn = m1[x].avarn+amount;
                        fwrite(&m1,sizeof(m1),1,f1);
                    }
                }
            }
        break;
        }

    case 5:
        {
            printf("Thanks!");
            exit(0);
        }
    default:
        {
            printf("Invalid input!");
            exit(0);
            break;
        }

    }
}
 fclose(f1);
 return 0;
}
```

The program will execute and run but it will not store any data that I add when I buy or sell stocks, I'm still learning file operations, can someone correct this program or tell me how to do it? I feel like the `fwrite()` function is maybe not taking in the values I'm giving it The program will execute and run but it will not store any data that I add when I buy or sell stocks, I'm still learning file operations, can someone correct this program or tell me how to do it? I feel like the `fwrite()` function is maybe not taking in the values I'm giving it

Comment: Use `puts()` to print lines of output, or include a newline at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong operator for testing equality.

```
if(f1=NULL)
```

This statement will *assign* `NULL` to `f1`, which will then evaluate to false.

You should use `if (f1 == NULL)` to test if it's NULL.  Or just simply `if (f1)`.

Something else strange that you are doing is opening the file twice, leaking the first handle.  You should close it first, or open it only once.

Also, you should pay attention to the open mode.  Your second call will actually destroy the file's contents.  Read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen#Parameters).

Comment: Thanks for the reply !, sorry about the (f1=NULL), i made a mistake while copying program here. I did as you said and removed the double opening for the file 1 and instead just made it rb+, still the problem persists, whenever i rerun the program to check the data present in the file 4.DAT it just shows the original table and not the modified one. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)